# Importing two columns and dividing the second column into many columns and rows based on a different delimiter and based on the first column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a hard challenge and tbh I am not sure if this is even possible using MYSQL

Let's say I have a table that has 3 columns

```
---------------------------------------------------
| gt3  | sv  | 12.1//1.3//4.5///3.3//3.3//3.4      |
| gt2  | sd  | 13.4//13//12.22///5.5//5.1//5.7     |
| gt1  | eer | 12//33                              |
```

I am trying to import this table into my DB using Dbvisualizer and this is how it should look like:

```
-------------------------------
| gt3  | 12.1  | 1.3   |  4.5  |
| gt3  | 3.3   | 3.3   |  3.4  |   
| gt2  | 13.4  | 13    | 12.22 |
| gt2  | 5.5   | 5.1   | 5.7   |
| gt1  | 12    | 33    |       |
```

So I am ignoring the second column and splitting the third column based on the first one so // is a new column and /// is a new row

I have tried this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\youse\\fakemas.txt'
INTO TABLE SA2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '//'
LINES TERMINATED BY '///'
```

This is just splitting the third column correctly as I wish but without using the first column.

Comment: Looks pretty easy - look up the string functions INSTR (or LOCATE) and SUBSTRING. You may need conditional checks.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the data set and the result set. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know how many rows might be represented, you can do:

```
select col1, 
       substring_index(rowvals, '//', 1),
       (case when rowvalues like '%//%' 
             then substring_index(substring_index(rowvals, '//', 2), '//', -1)
        end),
       (case when rowvalues like '%//%//%' 
             then substring_index(rowvals, '//', -1)
        end)
from (select t.*,
             substring_index(substring_index(col3, '///', n.n), '///', -1) as rowvals
      from t join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2) n
           on col3 like concat('%', repeat('///%', n.n - 1))
     ) t
```